# Java calculate 1*3*5*7*...* to user given double

Tags: java

i am trying to make java program that ask number from user and runs following calculation: `1*3*5*7*....*usergivendouble.` I think for loop is best for this but not sure how to make such loop. i tried

```
for(double i=1;i<=n;i+=2)
{
    n*= 2;
}
```

but it just never stops asking new number.
im new to java and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `n` supposed to be the limit, or the product? because you're trying to use it for both, which will cause you problems.

Comment: What do you mean "never stops asking new number"?

Comment: Why would the stopping number be a double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `n` is the user given number, increasing `n` inside the loop is the problem. You increase `n` inside the loop and also use it as the loop's end condition. This causes an infinite loop, as the loop's condition is never met.

You need to change the code to be:

```
double multiplyRestult=1;
for(double i=1;i<=n;i+=2)
{
    multiplyRestult*= i;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot man, this worked! still trying to get my head around for loops, theyre quite interesting

Comment: no problem, happy to help. You can read more about loops here: https://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Loops